# numpy interp decreasing xp

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I want to interpolate a numpy array, and the np.interp does almost exactly what I want:

```
interp(x, xp, fp, left=None, right=None)
One-dimensional linear interpolation.
```

Except for this bit:

> Does not check that the x-coordinate sequence `xp` is increasing.
>   If `xp` is not increasing, the results are nonsense.

My xp is decreasing, so which is better:
Reversing the direction of both xp an fp:

```
np.interp(x, xp[::-1], fp[::-1])
```

or inverting x and xp:

```
np.interp(-x, -xp, fp)
```

Or is there an even better way?

Comment: Any difference in the results?

Comment: @hpaulj Not that I can see.

Comment: I think the first one may be better, because no temp array will be generated in the process.

Comment: Unfortunately `interp` requires a contiguous array to work on (see the source [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L533)), which the reversed view isn't. So even though @kattern's suggestion seems like a good one, it will still generate temp arrays. Just 2 instead of 3, so it may still be the better option.

Comment: @Jaime Interesting, never look into the detail implementation of numpy's code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all those that have given their input, especially @Jaime.

I have experimented a bit, and came to this conclusion:

1) Apart from rounding errors, both methods mentioned by me have the same result.

2) They both take very much the same amount of time

3) I tried the scipy version, but it would reject the assume_sorted flag. Maybe my version of scipy is outdated. I suspect that if that flag is raised, scipy internally sorts the arrays. But the values are sorted, just in the opposite direction, so it doesn't need to do this.

Anyway, I'll use the reverse-direction method:

```
np.interp(x, xp[::-1], fp[::-1])
```

Just remember that in this case, you'll also have to reverse `left` and `right`, if you need them.

Comment: This solution does not account for both cases of ordered and non ordered x values. The assume_sorted option in the interpolate.interp1d function should work for you.

Comment: As per the question, in my case the x values are ordered, just in decreasing order. And no, the `assume_sorted=False` option did not work for me because my version of `scipy` is too old.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html), you could use the function interp1d, which has the keyword `assume_sorted=False` to handle decreasing arrays.

Edit: This solution handles both the cases of ordered and non ordered x values.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Decreasing array
x = np.arange(0, 10)[::-1]
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)

# Interpolation object
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, assume_sorted = False)

xnew = np.arange(3,5)
ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew, '-')
plt.show()
```